# docker/build-push-action@v4 creating cache entry each time

Tags: docker, github-actions, buildx

I have the following GitHub action:

```
- name: Build arm64 image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          file: test/extra/arm64_dockerfile
          platforms: linux/arm64
          load: true
          push: false
          tags: tinygrad-arm64
          cache-from: type=gha,src=src=/tmp/.buildx-cache
          cache-to: type=gha,dest=src=/tmp/.buildx-cache-new,mode=max
```

It correctly caches the dependencies of the project, the problem is that every time I run it a new cache is saved in GitHub caches and it doesn't delete the old one. Does anyone know if there is a way to avoid this?